# How does one set the width of images in org-mode for export to Markdown?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, markdown, exporting

I've tried both `#+ATTR_ODT: :width 570px` and `#+ATTR_MARKDOWN: :width 570px` but neither of them work. The image just takes the full width by default. This problem does not happen when I export to HTML using `#+ATTR_HTML: :width 570px`.

PS: I'm using Emacs version 27.1. Also, I'm interested in the GitHub-flavoured Markdown.

Comment: Please don't post the same question to StackOverflow and emacs.SE. Choose one to keep and delete the other. Thx.

Comment: `ox-odt` recognizes `#+ATTR_ODT: 5`. The number (and it's got to be a number: `570px` won't work) specifies the width of the image *in centimeters*, so try something small. The only way I know to specify the size of an image in Markdown is to tweak the exporter to produce HTML `<img>` tags for it and modify the size in that (which more or less defeats the purpose, but Markdown just does not provide any "native" markup for image size AFAIK).